# What is the difference between CentOS "DVD" vs "Everything" ISOs

Tags: centos

What is the difference between the DVD ISO and the Everything ISO?  These options are presented on the CentOS [download page](http://www.centos.org/download/) but there is no explanation as to what the difference is.

Comment: Section #3 discusses it a bit: http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7#head-76148df6f2cc6a03ab2ceaa23204ace3e2acbfb9

Comment: To add to this, the current CentOS7 ISOs sizes:
Minimal - 636MB
DVD - 4.0GB
Everything - 7.1GB Hope this will help guide you in which one to pick.

Comment: And it looks like the everything image has been removed for Centos 8. Any idea why?

Answer (score 52):

CentOS sure keeps this information well hidden.  Excerpts from this [link](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7):

> Various installation images are available for installing CentOS. Which image you need to download depends on your installation environment. All of these images can either be burned on a DVD or dd’ed to an USB memory stick.
>
> If you are unsure which image to use, pick the **DVD** image. It allows selecting which components you want to install.
>
> Live media images are also available, both for Gnome and KDE desktop environments. These allow you to test out CentOS by booting from the DVD or USB stick. The third livecd image uses Gnome, and as the livecd name implies, it is small enough to fit on a CD. This image does not contain libreoffice. You can also install CentOS to your hard disk from the live media images, but please note that what gets installed on your hard disk is exactly the same as you see when using the live media. For more flexibility in selecting which packages you want to have installed, please use the DVD image.
>
> The **everything** image contains all the packages that are available for CentOS-7, including those that are not directly installable from the installer. If you want to install those other packages, you must mount the install media on your installed system after the installation, and copy or install the packages from there. For most users installing from the DVD image and then installing the other packages with ”yum install ” instead is probably easier.

Comment: The most important/telling statement from the quote above: `For most users installing from the DVD image and then installing the other packages with ”yum install ” instead is probably easier.`

Answer (score 19):

The "DVD" ISO is small enough that you can burn it to a single-layer DVD (~4.7Gbyte). The rest of the software will be downloaded via the Internet if you chose to install it.

Answer (score 7):

Just found the answer in one of the "Readme" files

[README.txt](http://centos.ufes.br/6/isos/i386/0_README.txt)

**CentOS-6.7-i386-netinstall.iso**

> This is the network install and rescue image.
>     This image is designed to be burned onto a CD. You then boot your computer off the CD.

**CentOS-6.7-i386-minimal.iso**

> The aim of this image is to install a very basic CentOS 6.7 system, with the minimum of packages needed to have a functional system.
>     Please burn this image onto a CD and boot your computer off it. A preselected set of packages will be installed on your system. Everything else needs to be installed using yum.
>     The set of packages installed by this image is identical to the one installed when choosing the group named "Minimal" from the full DVD image.

**CentOS-6.7-i386-bin-DVD1 (2).iso**

> These two dvd images contain the entire base distribution.
>     Please burn DVD1 onto a DVD and boot your computer off it.
>     A basic install will not need DVD2.
>     After the installation is complete, please run "yum update" in order to update your system.

**CentOS-6.7-i386-LiveCD.iso**

> This is a CD live image of CentOS 6.7 designed to be burned onto a CD. You then boot your computer using that CD.
>     The disk can also be used to install CentOS 6.7 onto your computer but without offering any package selection options at install time.

**CentOS-6.7-i386-LiveDVD.iso**

> This is a DVD live image of CentOS 6.7 designed to be burned onto a DVD. You then boot your computer using that DVD.
>     The disk can also be used to install CentOS 6.7 onto your computer but without offering any package selection options at install time.

Remember that in order to be able to partition your disk you will need to run the GUI installer which in turns needs enough RAM. The same is true for the network setup step.
 The release notes ( http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.7 ) provide more details about these aspects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [README.txt](https://mirrors.aliyun.com/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/0_README.txt) file in the directory where you downloaded the image:

> CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso
> This DVD image contains all the packages that can be installed using the
> installer. This is the recommended image for most users.
>
> CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-2009.iso
> This is the network install and rescue image. The installer will ask from
> where it should fetch the packages to be installed. This image is most
> useful if you have a local mirror of CentOS packages.
>
> CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-2009.iso
> This image contains the complete set of packages for  CentOS Linux 7. It can be
> used for installing or populating a local mirror. This image needs a 16GB USB
> flash drive as it is too large for DVD isos.
>
> CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-2009.iso
> CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveKDE-2009.iso
> These images are Live images of  CentOS Linux 7. Depending on the name they use the
> respective display manager. They are designed for testing purposes and
> exploring the  CentOS Linux 7 environment. They will not modify the content of your
> hard disk, unless you choose to install  CentOS Linux 7 from within the Live
> environment. Please be advised that you can not change the set of installed
> packages in this case. This needs to be done within the installed system
> using 'yum'.
>
> CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-2009.iso
> The aim of this image is to install a very basic  CentOS Linux 7 system, with the
> minimum of packages needed to have a functional system. Please burn this image
> onto a CD and boot your computer off it. A preselected set of packages will be
> installed on your system. Everything else needs to be installed using yum. The set
> of packages installed by this image is identical to the one installed when choosing
> the group named "Minimal" from the full DVD image.